# year total not changing according to month selection in MDX

Tags: mdx

I want to bring the year totals to the report, but the year totals should remain the same in the month selection. I just want the year totals to change in the year selection. what can I do to achieve the same

```
SUM(FILTER 
([Time].[Year-Month].children,[Tarih].[Year-Month].CurrentMember.NAME < FORMAT(DATEADD("Y",1,Now()), "yyyyMM"))
,[Measures].[Target])
```

Comment: Please post an example or a screenshot to illustrate

Answer (score 0):

There are various properties in `MDX`  - I'm unsure `.NAME` is correct - you can try some of the other properties:

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.MemberName AS   
   [Date].[Calendar].[July 1, 2003].Properties('Name')  
MEMBER Measures.MemberVal AS   
   [Date].[Calendar].[July 1, 2003].Properties('Member_Value')  
MEMBER Measures.MemberKey AS   
   [Date].[Calendar].[July 1, 2003].Properties('Key')  
MEMBER Measures.MemberID AS   
   [Date].[Calendar].[July 1, 2003].Properties('ID')  
MEMBER Measures.MemberCaption AS   
   [Date].[Calendar].[July 1, 2003].Properties('Caption')
```

Also it is safer to add a conversion around the `NOW()` function:

```
FORMAT(DATEADD("Y",1, CDATE(Now())), "yyyyMM")
```